# Adding a 'break' command to algpseudocode pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

I want to add a `\Break` command to `algpseudocode`, which will display the word 'break' in the same font as 'return' is displayed. I've read the algpseudocode manual, but it only seems to explain how to define custom blocks, rather than individual commands. How would I add it?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is it not just `\newcommand*{\Break}{\textbf{break}}`?

Comment: To do it, as the package does it, you can simply read `grep -in return $(kpsewhich algpseudocode.sty)` and roll your own command similar: `46:\algnewcommand\algorithmicreturn{\textbf{return}}`
`83:\algnewcommand\Return{\algorithmicreturn{} }%`